# How to make insert statement re-runnable?

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

Need to add two following insert statements:

```
insert into table1(schema, table_name, table_alias) 
values ('ref_owner','test_table_1','tb1');

insert into table1(schema, table_name, table_alias) 
values ('dba_owner','test_table_2','tb2');
```

Question is how can I make those two insert statements re-runnable meaning, if those two insert statement are compiled again, it should throw row exists error or something along those lines...?

Additional notes:
1. I've seen examples of Merge in Oracle however, thats only when you're using two tables to match records. In this case im only using a single table. 
2. The table does not have any primary, unique or foreign keys - only check constraints on one of the columns.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: With your setup only possible solution is to write a delete script, that would remove the duplicates and run it periodically. This will 1) motivate you to thing about a *primary key* (aka how can I recognise a duplicated row?) and you can 2) compare your *insert* / *delete* approach with the alternative of defining unique constraint on your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a MERGE statement, as follows:

```
MERGE into table1 t1
  USING (SELECT 'ref_owner' AS SCHEMA_NAME, 'test_table_1' AS TABLE_NAME, 'tb1' AS ALIAS_NAME FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'dba_owner', 'test_table_2', 'tb2' FROM DUAL) d
    ON (t1.SCHEMA = d.SCHEMA_NAME AND
        t1.TABLE_NAME = d.TABLE_NAME)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ALIAS) 
    VALUES (d.SCHEMA_NAME, d.TABLE_NAME, d.ALIAS_NAME)
```

Best of luck.

Comment: With this approach how can I add multiple inserts (guessing need to alter the USING SELECT statement) and add inserts underneath?

Comment: Answer updated to show how to add a second row, per your example data. This assumes your data is all coming from literals. If your data resides in a table, of course, you can just select from your table in the USING clause and perform the appropriate join in the `ON` clause. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You **should** have a primary key, especially when you want to check for duplicate records and data integrity.

Provide a primary key for your table, or, if you somehow do not want to do that, create a unique constraint for all of the columns in the table, so no duplicate rows are possible.